# Why is 215510*10000 != 2155100000?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
UINT64 time1 = 215510*10000;
UINT64 time2 = (UINT64)(215510 * 10000);
```

When printing them or in Watch, it turns out:

```
time1 = 18446744071569684320
time2 = 18446744071569684320
```

---

Actually I know how to make it right here. We have to use one of the following codes in order to get correct answer (the following 3 versions are all right):

```
UINT64 time3 = (UINT64)215510 * 10000;
UINT64 time4 = 215510 * (UINT64)10000;
UINT64 time5 = (UINT64)215510 * (UINT64)10000;
```

---

But why the first two lines cannot give the right answer?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: No, it's not a duplicate. The other question is about floating-point arithmetic; this is purely integer arithmetic.

Comment: `215510*10000` is an `int` because both operands are `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a literal constant like `215510` is *usually* an `int` (not a `long`) in standard C++. It is not related to Visual Studio (it should be the same with another compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) a.k.a. `g++` at least if `int`-s have 32 bits), so `215510 * 10000`  is also an `int`. Try `215510L * 10000` to have one multiplicand be a `long` (hence the product also be a `long` - that won't change the product if `long`-s are still 32 bits!), or even `215510LL` to make it `long long` or with a explicit cast `(int64_t)215510` ...

And on your platform, `int` are probably 32 bits. So the signed `INT_MAX` is `2147483647` (which is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1).

And [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) commented rightly that

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list
>   in which its value can be represented.

per (the C11 standard §6.4.4.1 item 5 or) the C++11 standard §2.14.2 item 2. So on an implementation with 16 bits `int`-s and 32 bits `long`-s  `215510` is a `long` literal constant (because 215510 > 32767 which would be its `INT_MAX`....).

<sup>So contrarily to what I believed, the type of a literal integral constant is not defined by its suffix -or lack of it- alone, but also by its value!</sup>

Comment: `215510` is of type `int` only if `int` is big enough to hold it. `int` can be as narrow as 16 bits, which makes `INT_MAX` 32767; on such a system, `215510` would be of type `long`.

Comment: If `long` also has 32 bits, this answer won't be useful. And according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx), it does.

Comment: @KeithThompson: are you sure of that? I thought the standard typed literal constants independently of their value (only using the suffix `L` etc... or lack of it)!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Keith Thompson is entirely correct. It wouldn't be useful to give a constant of, say, 60000, a type of `int` if it cannot be represented in an `int`. On other systems, it might still be `int`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes.

Comment: It is not a matter of usefulness, but of standards.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understand that. My point is, the folks that write and edit the standard use their brains, so when I think "huh? that's stupid.", I know it's a good idea to double-check what the standard *really* says. :)

Comment: Again you've taken my comment as saying the opposite of what I both meant and posted. Oh well, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 11):

It's because you are invoking integer overflow by multiplying two 32-bit numbers whose result is larger than 32 bits.  You need to convert to 64 bits first, as you have already shown.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, an unsuffixed integer literal has type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, whichever is the first in which its value can be represented. (`long long int` was a relatively recent addition to the language.)

Probably on your system both `215510` and `10000` are of type `int`, which is probably a 32-bit type.

Expressions are (usually) evaluated by themselves, without regard to the context in which they appear. So the expression `215510*10000` is evaluated as an `int`. Since the mathematical result exceeds `INT_MAX`, the result is undefined, but it's likely to be `-2139867296`.

When that value is converted to a 64-bit unsigned type, it wraps around, yielding `18446744071569684320` (which is slightly less than 2<sup>64</sup>).

Comment: The literal constant `215510` is *always* an `int` (this is not system specific, it is required by the standard).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's incorrect. I suggest you check your sources. Quoting the 2003 ISO C++ standard, 2.13.1p2: "The type of an integer literal depends on its form, value, and suffix.  If it is decimal and has no suffix, it has
the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `long int`; if the value cannot be represented as a `long int`, the behavior is undefined." The 2011 standard adds `long long int` and shows the rules in a table.